# How can I decrease the size of my picture and turn it into a parallax effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically, I am trying to create a webpage for Nikola Telsa. I have already made the navigation bar, but the image is very big. I would like the image to be much smaller, showing his face. I have tried adjusting the size of the width and height, but the picture does not take up the entire screen if I change the values. In addition, I would also like to turn the image into a parallax scrolling effect. Is there anyway I can change the width and height so it is smaller and make the image have a parallax effect? Any help is appreciated. Thanks. Here is my code.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    var header = document.querySelector("header");
    header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
 
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
 
body{
    background: black;
    min-height: 200vh;
}
 
header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between; 
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.6s;
    padding: 40px 100px;
    z-index: 100000;
}

header.sticky{
    padding: 5px 100px;
    background: #fff;
}
 
header .logo{
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

header ul{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

header ul li{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

header ul li a{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 500px;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

.banner{
    position: relative;
    background: url(tesla.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;

}

header.sticky .logo, header.sticky ul li a{
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inventions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Museum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Quotes</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <section class="banner"></section>
    <script src="nav.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is the image in the code?

Comment: This is the link to the image I am using: https://www.ocduk.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Nikola-Tesla-OCDUK.jpg

Comment: Instead of saying you want a "parallax effect", explain the precise effect that you want, since parallax effects come in many different forms.

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
        var header = document.querySelector("header");
        header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
    })
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
 
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
 
body{
    background: black;
    min-height: 200vh;
}
 
header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between; 
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.6s;
    padding: 40px 100px;
    z-index: 100000;
}

header.sticky{
    padding: 5px 100px;
    background: #fff;
}
 
header .logo{
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

header ul{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

header ul li{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

header ul li a{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 500px;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

.banner{
    position: relative;
    background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Tesla_circa_1890.jpeg) no-repeat;
    //background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1200px;

}

header.sticky .logo, header.sticky ul li a{
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inventions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Museum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Quotes</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <section class="banner"></section>
    <script src="nav.js"></script>
```

I have added background attachment css in banner class and comment out background size cover.